# python: input variable of function append changes while changing host-variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm facing (for me at least) some kind of strange behavior while using the function append in python. In the following example the variable *growing* is appended with value of the variable *static*. Then a value in *growing* is changed which influences also the variable *static*. Why is this happening? I thought *static* should not change until I assign a new value e.g. with 'static = ...'.

Tested with Python 3.7.4 (default, Jul 16 2019, 07:12:58) [GCC 9.1.0] on linux

Code:

```
static = {"a": 100, "b": 200}
growing = []
print("static", static)
print("growing", growing)
growing.append(static)
growing[0]["a"] = 999
print('after append and change in growing:')
print("static", static)
print("growing", growing)
```

This is the output I get:

```
static {'a': 100, 'b': 200}
growing []
after append and change in growing:
static {'a': 999, 'b': 200}
growing [{'a': 999, 'b': 200}]
```

Comment: Because `growing[0] is static`; you appended a *reference* to that dictionary to the list. You might find https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html useful reading.

Comment: `growing[0]` and `static` point to the same underlying object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static = {"a": 100, "b": 200}
```

Above statement creates a dict object in memory and the variable "static" points to that.

```
growing.append(static)
```

When you append static to growing , the first element of the list points to same dict object in memory. No new object is created , just 2 variables static and growing[0] are pointing to same object in memory. Thus when this dict is changed by

```
growing[0]["a"] = 999
```

you see the change in both the variables

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and comments. As an old Matlab user, this was totally new to me. Thanks :)